# How to add Dynamic Slidebar/NavBar In Angular Fuse using FuseNavigationService

Tags: angular

I'm trying to build an angular application in which I am using Fuse for Angular theme,in this project I want to add dynamic elements to the sidebar.

For this I tried to use the method provided by FuseNavigationService i.e. FuseNavigationService.addNavigationItem(item: any, id: any)
but I'm unable to find any help online for this method and how to use this method.

FuseNavigationService.addNavigationItem(item: any, id: any): void
Add a navigation item to the specified location

@param item

@param id

can anyone please suggest me how do I add dynamic sidebar using FuseNavigationService